# Constructing $R$-modules using formal sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $X=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ be a finite set and let $R$ be a ring.
We construct an $R$-module $M$ in the following way: an element $a$ in $M$ is a "formal sum" $a=\sum_ir_ix_i$ where $r_i $ are in $R$. The addition and external multiplication are clearly defined and they are induced from the addition and  the internal multiplication of the ring $R$ using the rules that $r_ix_i+s_ix_i=(r_i+s_i)x_i$ and $r_i(s_ix_i)=(r_is_i)x_i$.

What I don't understand is whether a formal sum is well defined mathematical object or just an abuse of notation. and the other thing is that would it be better to write a formal sum as an unordered set of $n$ couples $(r_i,x_i)\in  R\times X$. My last question is about the case the ring $R=\mathbb Z$, in this case the sum is not formal because $r_ix_i$ has a meaning which is the element $x_i$ considered $r_i$ times and in this case $M$ is the free abelian group on the set $
X$. What do we call $M$ if $R$ is not $\mathbb Z$.  Thank you for clearing these ideas out !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by addition is not well defined.  Note that addition is always commutative in a module or ring.

Comment: ok I edited my question.

Comment: This isn't *really* an answer to your question, but... perhaps you would prefer to think of your formal sums instead as functions $f \colon X \to R$ - you can then define all the operations exactly as you have. If I understand your notation, $M$ is usually called the free $R$-module on $X$, and is sometimes denoted $R^{X}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction you describe is that of a free $R$-module. It can be made precise.

Let $X$ be *any* set (it need not be finite, but then the following finiteness condition is superflous):

Let the elements of $M$ be functions $f : X \to R$ (families $(f_x)_{x\in X}$) , such that $\{f_x\neq 0 : x\in X\}$ is finite. Then define the module structure in the obvious fashion. Finally you can prove that a "copy" $X'$ of $X$ is a basis for $M$ and that $f = \sum_{x\in X'} f_x\cdot x$. This is well-defined because of the finiteness condition above.

Comment: I see that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $R$ but what is $f_x$, the notation is not clear, also does your answer mean that the formal sum construction is just an abuse of notation of what you are saying, and does not have a precise mathematical sense like the one you give and that's why it is called "formal" ?

Comment: $f_x$ is another way to write $f(x)$. Usually, you write $f_x$, if you think of $f$ as a family (think sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$). But there is no formal distinction between the two notations. - Yes, the "formal sum construction" is technically an abuse of notation. It is sufficient for describing the free module *after* constructing it, but not prior to that. I personally think this abuse of notation can initially be quite confusing to people unfamiliar with this (similarly for rings of polynomials).

Comment: I have no idea why it is called "formal" and I also find this terminology strange. It may have something to do with logic, i.e. how you can "formally" construct terms even without any "substance" to them (think vectors in $\mathbb R^2$), or something like that. But I'm only speculating.

Comment: what is special in this construction in  the case $R=\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: A $\mathbb Z$-module "is" the same thing as an abelian group. In an abelian group there is a canonical way to multiply elements with integers. A morphism between abelian groups is morphism of the corresponding $\mathbb Z$-modules: It preserves this scalar multiplication with integers. The statement that $\mathbb Z$-module and abelian groups are the same can be made precise with the help of category theory. In any case it is often of great help to think of abelian groups as $\mathbb Z$-modules.